# What does it mean "socials", in high school context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Three girls are chatting in the hall of a high school, in the US. At some point, the second bell rings and two girls branch off and head **to socials**, and the third one walks alone to math class. 
What does it mean "socials" in this context? The text doesn't provide further details.

Comment: *Social studies* - a sort of catchall term for history, sociology, geography, political science and so forth.

Comment: I agree that it must mean *social studies*, although I have never heard anyone just call it "socials".  Maybe it's newer slang since when I was in high school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in this context, it means to Social studies class.